# How to program frames in C++

Tags: c++, frames

OK, C++ noob here asking a very nooby question (sorry) but whenever I write my basic programs (helloworld etc.) they always appear in a command prompt window. I want to make proper windows like in Word and other programs. I know it is possible to do this because of all the programs I use every day. But how do I do this in C++? For all the Java veterans out there, I want it to be like a JFrame, but the C++ equivalent.

Comment: There is no C++ equivalent. You'll have to use some toolkit or platform-specific API such as the Windows API, which is what the toolkits use internally.

Comment: @imulsion standard C++ doesn't have GUI libraries, you need to learn how to link an external library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ doesn't have a UI library out of the box, so you need to choose one.

Popular options would be [MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e.aspx) (under Windows/Visual C++) or [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) (with quite a lot additional libraries and features, working on many platforms).

Comment: Sorry, don't really understand, want do u mean in really simple terms?

Comment: Well, in Java the UI classes are a part of the platform. In C++ it's not so -- you need to find a 3rd-party UI library.

Comment: UI? Sorry about the noobiness :)

Comment: UI = user interface :) With C++-the-language, you can only use `cout` and the like. In order to have windows/frames/whatever, you need a special library, which knows how to make them. Such a library is not included in C++ by default.

Comment: Ah.... so I need 2 download extra stuff?

Comment: @imulsion: Well, it depends. With Visual C++, MFC is included; with other C++ compilers not. As for Qt, yes, you'll need to download and install it. And configure, too :)

Comment: To clarify: as I understand it, there are 'standard' C++ libraries (like <iostream>) and u can get extra ones with QT and MFC, which allow u to do extra things. Is this correct?

Comment: @imulsion yes, those are called "libraries" and they let you reuse code other people have written in your program so you can save time and do things you might not know how to do otherwise.

Comment: All becomes clear! Thanks for this u guys, I understand! :D

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention Word, it appears that you're on the Windows platform.

Then consider starting with e.g. the **[Lessons in Windows API Programming (C++)](http://learnwinapi.wordpress.com/)** hands-on tutorial.

There are also a great many other tutorials on the net, and books to buy. I just picked the one that I was most familiar with, as the author. Regarding books, the classic book on programming the Windows API is Petzold's "Windows Programming", but I seem to recall that the latest version is for Windows 8 and in C# (earlier version were C/C++).

The tutorial leads you through how to get started with creating window programs using the Windows API (Application Program Interface) direcetly.

This is fairly language independent, but the language used in the tutorial is C++. C++ doesn't have standard library support for GUI stuff. The idea in C++ is that you're free to use whatever third party libraries that you want, *or create them*, such as the Windows API.

Comment: Thanks a lot! First answer I actually understand :D Sorry 2 all of u others, I feel stupid now

Comment: @imulsion since you seem to be a beginner you might have an easier time with the QT framework since it has a very nice learning curve compared to WinAPI.

Comment: @Rapptz: for a beginner it's not that way. QT has a short learning curve for someone well versed in C++ and GUI programming. For that person, the Windows API takes longer to get a grip on, because there are more details to handle. For the beginner it is opposite. Learning QT involves learning a lot about both C++ and GUI stuff before one can get productive, while the Windows API is at the C level, so, one does not have to learn advanced new language things. Also, there's nothing to install or configure, also convenient for the beginner. :-)

Comment: Qt is much nicer than Win32. Win32 UI development is extremely error prone. Qt has another huge advantage: it is not tied to Windows, you can build your program for several operating systems and architectures.

Answer (score 2):

This is highly platform dependent. You can use a GUI cross-platform library, like QT, or use native mechanisms. Under Windows you can use the WinAPI and MFC.

Comment: What is QT? Can u provide links 2 helpful websites or explain how to do this?

Comment: @imulsion: Is your google broken?